# python Deep learning load image dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm new to deep learning.
I feel so stupid myself, because I'm asking many questions during one day.

I'm loading images through glob, and I'm heading a problem.

I planned to load images to numpy, and I hope it's shape: width * height * imagecounts (only 1 shape), but it is not.
I wants 128*128*242, and the result is 128, 128, 3( and I don't know where the '3' come from.)

I think, one of the problem is I need to load whole images, but every time I renew the data into new image, and not calculating the counts.

I'm learning about 'deep learning' to make 'deep learning', and I really want to make it on my own later, please help.

Data example:

```
[[255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
      ...
 [255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]]
```

Here's my code

```
def _load_img():
# I get data_list with
# data_list = glob('dataset\\training\\*\\*.jpg')
    for v in data_list: 
        data = np.array(Image.open(v))

#img_size : 128 * 128
#I reshaped the data to get 242 the number of images count.
    data = data.reshape(-1, img_size)

    return data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are typically in `RGB` format, resulting in 3 channels, and thus 128*128* **3** * 242.

Since you do not want to  lose your RGB information, you could use:

```
data = data.reshape(-1, img_size * 3)
```

This is why conventional image-processing architectures have their input channel set to 3, considering `RGB`. Black and white datasets such as MNIST only have one channel, though.

[image: VGGNet architecture]

Note the 224 x 224 x 3 in the beginning.

```
Image size: 224 X 224
Channel size (RGB) : 3
```

[EDIT]

```
for v in data_list: 
        data = np.array(Image.open(v))
```

You are not adding your newly created array anywhere. Maybe create a list to handle all your images:

```
data = [np.array(Image.open(v)) for v in data_list]
```

However, loading in all your images before processing them is quite inefficient, so loading your image one by one WHEN they are needed is a good practice. But this should fix your issue at hand?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not going to forget the channel now.
However on my result, there is no shape for image count. Only 128*128*3. 
I need to get the image counts for the shape, but it doesn't work. I tried many ways to put, maybe I miss something.